# How to get HTML with “JavaScript enabled”?

Tags: javascript, php, html, stream

I would like to get the HTML code from a page with PHP. So I do this:

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City';
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

The problem is, Wikipedia doesn't send the `<script>` tag to the PHP request, so it doesn't show the JavaScript.
I guess that's because Wikipedia sees that the "requester" doesn't have JavaScript enabled, so it doesn't send the `<script>` tags.

How can I let Wikipedia know that my PHP is *JavaScript enabled*?

I heard about stream context, but I don't know how to set *JavaScript enabled* for it.

Comment: **file_get_html** is not in the default php library. Where did you take this function from?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. file_get_html is a function of simple_html_dom.

Comment: try faking a user-agent for a javascript capable browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to symcbean, here's the solution.

I added:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
```

And now it's sending the corret script block.

;)

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Tested it on my local PHP server.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It's always getting the html without any javascript. So maybe it depends on the configuration of the server? I'm testing it in this free hosting http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/phpinfo-default_variables.html <- phpinfo()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `file_get_html()` function is stripping away the `<script>` blocks, because I tried to request `GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1` from Fiddler without any request headers, and it did return the `<script>` blocks in the response.

Comment: It's doing the same with file_get_contents. Could it depends on the user-agent?

Comment: @DavidDev: I tried in Fiddler without the user-agent header, and I still received the `<script>` blocks. It could in theory serve different content according to the user-agent, but I doubt wikipedia is doing that. It would complicate their caching processes.

Comment: Hmm I have no idea. I'll try on another webserver. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score -5):

You could use an Iframe.

You could also use something like jQuery to grab the page (or certain parts of the page) onto your website.

Comment: wow, some people really do believe jquery is the answer to everything. He does specify he is looking for a PHP solution.

Comment: Also, you can't scrape another page with JavaScript alone... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy